# Instances gets stuck in Active state under Biztalk hat query

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

We are experiencing a problem during message processing in Biztalk server 2012 here while processing messages their instances gets stuck in active state however their messages gets process successfully.

If we do not terminate the active instance then they impact the future coming messages.

Comment: can you provide more details such as, 1) what service instance it is? is it orchestration instance or send port 2) if send port, then is it marked ordered delivery 3) what impact you have future incoming messages

Comment: Hi Vikas, 1.) These service instance belongs to Messaging service class and they are send port instance 2.)  Yes, send port is marked ordered delivery3.) Future incoming messages belongs to this send port gets stuck inside the messages part of the send port, then we manually resume them, after that they gets process.

Comment: Order delivery send port instances always remain active, that's how they are designed. Any new message goes to same send port instance by BizTalk and should process the messages fine. Can you tell what you mean by Stuck? do they get suspended? If an instance get suspended due to a failure on top message, then all other messages will be queued up due to order delivery. You need to check the reason of why the message at top is getting suspended (check eventviewer logs). Also do not use order delivery send ports unless you need to send messages in order.

Comment: Hi Vikas, Thanks for the response, here stuck means when i clicked on the send port instance that is present in active state then under its messages part i can see the queued messages, then i resume those messages present under send port messages part by right clicking them. In event viewer i didn't find any error related to them

Comment: Can you send a screen shot if possible? You can't resume messages if they are not suspended. if they are suspended then there has to be some error

Comment: HI Vikas, Is there any better alternatives to Ordered Delivery?

Comment: Ordered delivery is needed only when you need to send messages in order. Otherwise you can just uncheck order delivery option. Do you need ordered delivery?

Comment: Yes we need ordered delivery but because of it we are facing issue as mentioned above, so i am looking for its alternative. Is there any alternative of it?

Comment: As I said, provide the screen shot of issue/error you are getting. ordered delivery works great, haven't seen any issue with this so far

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you have a port set to Ordered Delivery then there will be an instance for that port that will persist.  This is expected behaviour as this is how it ensures that messages are delivered in order by having a single instance that processes all the messages for that port.

If you also tick "Stop sending subsequent messages on current message failure" and there is an error then all messages after the current one will wait until you either have resumed the messages successfully or have terminated that message (be careful not the terminate the instance as that would terminate ALL of the messages queued up for that port).

The only time that instance will go away is if you terminate it (dangerous to do) or the host or server is restarted.  It will re-appear and persist as soon as a new message is received for that port.